# Detect if website is being served thru a proxy server like Opera Mini?

Tags: javascript, mobile, proxy, amazon-ec2, opera

Many feature phones use [Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/mobile/help/faq/) to [serve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249255/770127) webpages. Similarly Kindle Fire uses [Amazon Silk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Silk). Is there a way in JavaScript to detect that a proxy is being used without UA detection?

Comment: JavaScript on the server side or on the client side?

Comment: @icktoofay On the client side.

Answer (score 1):

In Opera Mini's case: no. The JavaScript will in fact be executed by the "proxy server", not  by the real client.

Comment: There is a straight forward way for detecting opera mini `var isOperaMini = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.operamini) === "[object OperaMini]"` (http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-and-javascript/)

Comment: Well, yes - you can detect that "Opera mini" is used, but that's not what the question was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

My hypothesis is that such cloud based browsers cannot support a subset of events. For detecting such browsers I am using a javascript test that checks support for an event `scroll`.

```
var cloudBrowser = ('onscroll' in window?false:true);
```

I was able to find this working successfully on opera mini on my android (Samsung Galaxy Note 2) and also on Nokia C2-03 browser. (I was unable to check this for Amazon Silk as I do not have the device).

Do let me know if you are aware of any other cloud browsers for android that I can download and extend the testing.