# <!DOCTYPE html> removes media queries styles

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I build a wp template with the following in the header:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

In the stylesheet I use @media queries, eg:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
#wrapper {width:1280px;}
}
```

Style and template was fine until I noticed I missed the doctype, so I added this to the header as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

No all the styles are incorrect, media queries seem to be ignored, I can see no style in the developer inspector (Firefox, chrome, safari etc).

If I remove  the style in the media queries are shown, add it again the styles are removed.

Issue is see on all browswer.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Comment: Why are you adding that meta tag?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> use this meta

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vhCLs/16/ `DOCTYPE` has no affect on media queries.. something else is wrong.

Comment: @Atif Azad I have the viewport metatag included but makes no difference

Comment: @Pogrindis I only see the issue when <!DOCTYPE html> is added, removing it and the styles are correct. All styles in the media queries are dropped. I agree that something else is causing it though.

Answer (score 1):

Doctype has no effect on your media queries.

You can add some support though .

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

These will offer cross browser reference support and will most likely solve your issue.

See similar post : [CSS3 Media Queries - does not work in some browsers (officially supporting MQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246903/css3-media-queries-does-not-work-in-some-browsers-officially-supporting-mq)

Comment: stupid question but @TJ15 are you **absolutely** sure the CSS file has been loaded ?

Comment: defo loaded, all the base styles and media queries are in one style sheet, the base styles are OK. Anything in the media queries is lost once I add the doctype.

Comment: @TJ15 make sure you only have 1 DOCTYPE then specified and make sure wordpress is not wrapping it with one already : http://validator.w3.org/ and if its working without you specifying one.. why specify ? If its not broken, don't fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a style class I was applying to a DIV.

`.aclass { ... }` within @media and a `min-width` "disappeared" when I added the `DOCTYPE` html tag, then "reappeared" and worked when I removed the `DOCTYPE`.

Explicitly including the element in question solved the disappearing act, that is...

`DIV.aclass { ... }` works properly.